# String representation of arrays in python

Tags: python

Is there anything that performs the following, in python? Or will I have to implement it myself?

```
array = [0, 1, 2]
myString = SOME_FUNCTION_THAT_TAKES_AN_ARRAY_AS_INPUT(array)
print myString
```

which prints

```
(0, 1, 2)
```

Thanks

Comment: 'print array' works... are you specifically interested in the parentheses?

Comment: You should know and use the various names of the sequence types, which are [list], (tuple,..) and {'dict':..}. They all have different behaviour. What you want is to convert a list to a tuple, and that can be done just by print tuple(list). See also Prasoon's answer, which is correct.

Comment: I think everyone has taken the question too literally, and what devoured elysium is looking for is just `str(array)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array's items are specifically integers, `str(tuple(array))` as suggested in @jboxer's answer will work.  For most other types of items, it may be more of a problem, since `str(tuple(...))` uses `repr`, **not** `str` -- that's really needed as a default behavior (otherwise `print`ing a tuple with an item such as the string `'1, 2'` would be extremely confusing, looking just like a string with the two int items `1` and `2`!-), but it may or may not be what you want.  For example:

```
>>> array = [0.1, 0.2]
>>> print str(tuple(array))
(0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001)
```

With floating point numbers, `repr` emits many more digits than make sense in most cases (while `str`, if called directly on the numbers, behaves a bit better).  So if your items are liable to be `float`s (as well as `int`s, which would need no precaution but won't be hurt by this one;-), you might better off with:

```
>>> print '(%s)' % (', '.join(str(x) for x in array))
(0.1, 0.2)
```

However, this might produce ambiguous output if some of the items are strings, as I mentioned earlier!

If you know what types of data you're liable to have in the `list` which you call "array", it would give a better basis on which to recommend a solution.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck, Python has a function for this purpose exactly. It's called `join`.

```
print "(" + ", ".join(array) + ")"
```

If you're familiar with PHP, `join` is similar to `implode`. The `", "` above is the element separator, and can be replaced with any string. For example,

```
print "123".join(['a','b','c'])
```

will print

```
a123b123c
```

Comment: This will work in your example, but not in the one the submitter gave, since he used ints. You could use ", ".join([str(x) for x in array]) though.

Answer (score 5):

```
def SOME_FUNCTION_THAT_TAKES_AN_ARRAY_AS_INPUT (arr):
    return str(tuple(arr))
```

Replace `str` with `unicode` if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

```
SOME_FUNCTION_THAT_TAKES_AN_ARRAY_AS_INPUT = tuple
```

Comment: The OP claims he wants a string (though his use of `print` obfuscates that;-).

Comment: I know.  My comment was more of a tongue-in-cheek remark, particularly because I got a kick out of his use of "SOME_FUNCTION_THAT_TAKES_AN_ARRAY_AS_INPUT". :-)